# Semi-total derivative approximation with varying finite difference steps

Tags: openmdao

I recently learned about the feature of the [semi-total derivative approximation](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/2.4.0/features/core_features/working_with_derivatives/approximating_totals.html). I started to use this feature with bsplines and an explicit component. My current problem is that my design variables are input from two different components similar to the xsdm below. As far as I see it is not possible to set up different finite difference steps for different design variables. So looking at the xsdm again the control points, x and z should have identical FD steps i.e.

model.approx_totals(step=1)

works but

model.approx_totals(step=np.ones(5))

won't work. I guess, one remedy is to use the relative step size but some of my input bounds are varying from 0 to xx so maybe the relative step size is not the best. Is there a way to feed in FD steps as a vector or something similar to ;

```
for out in outputs:
   for dep,fdstep in zip(inputs,inputsteps):
     self.declare_partials(of=out,wrt=dep,method='fd',step=fdstep, form='central')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of OpenMDAO V2.4, you don't have the ability to set per-variable FD step sizes when using `approx_totals`. The best option is just to use relative step sizes.